add optional elements when creating a python tuple
I have to create a truple (or array) with a variable number of elements. Given this minimal example:
def do_something(foo: str):
    my_tuple = (
       "item",
       *([foo] if foo is not None else []),
       "something"
    )
    ...

I wonder, is there a shorter than using the spread operator expression *([foo] if foo is not None else []) here to add an element optionally in the tuple? Note that using an if-statement is not an option to create different tuples. Adding a None element is also not an option. Execution time can also be neglected, preference is on minimizing the code and redundancy.
Edit: Down the line, should future Python versions have an dedicated way to express this, so foo is only used one?

Wow, I had no idea that even worked.  TIL.

"Note that using an if-statement is not an option to create different tuples." Why not?

@mozway this a minimal example from a more complex thing. So - because I said so.

@Axel if this is because you have multiple occurrences, why not just use a function? def f(foo): return ([foo] if foo is not None else []); b = 'b' ; d = None ; tup = ('a', *f(b), 'c', *f(d), 'e') -> ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e').

@mozway I am looking for something that is a "nice" expression. Without lambdas.


is there a shorter than using the spread operator *([foo] if foo is not None else [])

Yes, this can be done following way
foo = "foo"
my_tuple = ("item",*[foo][:foo is not None],"something")

but is harder to understand. It exploits boolean-as-integer trick, which is used to determine if 0 or 1-long prefix of list will be used, in former case this results in empty list.

Thanks, that is an unteresting pattern to keep in mind. But as you said, this might scare off even more people.

Allow the None to be in the tuple at first and then filter down.
def do_something(foo: str):
    my_tuple = (
       "item",
       foo,
       "something"
    )

    return tuple(filter(bool, my_tuple))


What if item or something is 0, or an empty string, or any other falsey value?

@John you could always run tuple(filter(lambda x: x is not None, my_tuple)), but this would not allow None in the other items of the tuple.

This would delete other items also, so it is not an option

Also, Python has some things that evaluate to false but are not None, see e.g. Path object.

@AxelHeider Aren't Path objects all true? How do you create a false one?

Good point, they likely never evaluate to None, but there was something where they evaluates to false, so this can a pit fall for naive if not style checks.
